# Error: "Err Too Many Redirect" Prestashop 1.7

Tags: redirect, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I get the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error just modules and products page on the prestashop admin panel. When i try to connect pages url is contain `...security/compromised...`. I was changed the all modules names for the making disable. But its not help to me.

How can i fix? Which methods can I try?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I have installed this version on my live server and noticed the same issue.
I had my shop enabled for SSL but not for all pages, soon as I enabled it for all pages my error went away.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

**Check your PHP setting for `session.save_path`**. It should be `/tmp`. Particularly if you've switched PHP versions around, it has a nasty habit of setting it to something like `/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72/`.

Comment: Question not speak about cpanel and on cpanel is not problem when you change php version. After change php version, htaccess change new path for sessions.

Comment: @abkrim Not relevant to my post. I used an example that happened to use cPanel, but it could have been anything. Not sure why you felt it was worth a downvote on a 7 month old post because you didn't like what folder I used as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to regenerate the .htaccess with SEO/URL in admin.

Answer (score 0):

try to disable and then to enable friendly url.
if that won'tt help please try to switch on the error in config/defines.inc.php ps_mod_dev in true
and please check out if you htaccess is generated

please send your htaccess